# Music module for Python

Tags: python, module, mp3, media

I'm struggling to find a module that fits all my needs. I need a module that works with Python 3.X.X, that can play, pause, and queue MP3 tracks. Pyglet was doing well but it hasn't been updated in years, and the Queue function doesn't work with Python 3. Any suggestions for what module I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Try [pysox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysox). It requires the development libraries of sox.